# how to manipulate records?

Tags: clojure

How to manipulate records?

Where could I find some examples?

I want to make a sequence to a records.
for example:

```
(defrecord Point [x y])
```

how to make a sequence of Points from '[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]]'?

and if the data store in a file:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

how to read these into the records?

```
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
  (doall (? (line-seq rdr))))))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure's `defrecord` generates some helper functions for the type being defined. Their purpose is to have constructors for the type as first-class Clojure citizens. In particular `defrecord Point` generates `map->Point` that takes a map and (this one is probably what you need) `->Point` that takes  positional arguments. So this:

```
(defrecord Point [x y])
(map (partial apply ->Point) [[1 2] [3 4]])
```

produces this:

```
(#user.Point{:x 1, :y 2} #user.Point{:x 3, :y 4})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `defrecord` declaration is correct.

You can then create instances of your point using the `(Name. <args>)` form

```
;=> (defrecord Point [ x y ])
user.Point
;=> (def p (Point. 1 2)
#user.Point{:x 1, :y 2}

; records have access of members 'as-if' they were a hash 
; (but more efficient)
;=> (:x p)
1

; sequence of points...    
;=> [(Point. 1 2)(Point. 3 4)(Point. 5 6)]
[#user.Point{:x 1, :y 2} #user.Point{:x 3, :y 4} #user.Point{:x 5, :y 6}]

; read from a whitespace separated file
;=> (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (doall (for [[x y] (map #(re-seq #"\w+" %) (line-seq rdr))]
         (Point. x y))))
(#user.Point{:x "1", :y "2"} #user.Point{:x "3", :y "4"} #user.Point{:x "5", :y "6"})
```

Comment: but what i want is make a sequences of points from a list. something like `(def seq (apply (Point.) [[1 2] [3 4]]))` I know this is not correct.

Comment: @JinZhang: Define a function `(defn make-point [x y] (Point. x y))`, then you can use `(map (partial apply make-point) [[1 2] [3 4]])`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any more convenient way to do this? without define a function. as I mentioned above, I need to read all data from a file, and transform it into a Points sequences. `(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
  (doall (_____ (line-seq rdr)))))) `

Comment: I added an example of reading from a whitespace separated file

Comment: Thanks. One more question, if the Point has n dimensions?

Comment: @JinZhang The rule of thumb is: if you label a dimension with `n` then better to use an array then a record. You'll probably need to iterate over the dimensions sooner or later and it is much more convenient with an array. Plus, in case of the array, the n does not have to be known at compile-time.

Comment: Actually, 5 < n < 10. I don't want to use a,b,c,d,e,f, so I prefer @Rafał Dowgird's method. Thanks anyway.